# How to fix incorrect font in Eclipse IDE on wayland without installing GNOME settings daemon?

Tags: kde, eclipse, wayland, gtk3

Currently Eclipse is almost unusable on Xorg due to the bug in SWT: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=568859

The only workaround I've deduced is trying the Wayland KDE session. But all the font settings are ignored there and fonts in GTK apps look like this (screenshot found at [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/swaywm/comments/bkzeo7/font_rendering_really_bad_and_rough_in_gtk3/))

[image: screenshot]

Firefox is fine though. At least determining the name of this font might help. And I **really** don't want to install `gnome-settings-daemon`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `xdg-desktop-portal-gtk` and relogin.